# Adjusting the proportional editing falloff curve continuously

Tags: add-on, proportional-editing

I'm a fresh noob Blender user who has learned to love the proportional editing tool. I've mostly benefitted of the 'sharp' falloff shape but at times hoped I could adjust the falloff curve somewhere between, say, linear and sharp (like the shape with the bevel tool). In fact, to me this feature seems so powerful and obvious that I've began to hope there would already be an addon to make it happen but have had no luck finding one. Maybe all you smart people here can help me with this.

Also, I'm a bit familiar with scripting and node based stuff on other environments so I have no problem with getting my hands dirty with either if it would allow to implement the described functionality.

Comment: Isn’t there a custom falloff option?

Comment: I sure hope so, but haven't been able to spot one. Maybe you would!